# css help on rule selection

Tags: html, css-selectors

I have what I think is a really simple css question. I have the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en-US">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700|PT+Serif:400,700">
      <style amp-custom>
         .sd-title {
            font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: 12px;
         }
         .single-post h3 {
            font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
            line-height: 1.6;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body class="single-post ">
       <h3 class="sd-title">Share this:</h3>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want "Share this:" to display using the font specified in the css rule for the class "sd-title" but instead it always uses the other css rule. I tried increasing the specificity of the sd-title rule but no matter what I do it won't use that rule. How can I modify the sd-title rule so it will be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using amp you can also use a more specific selector to override a subsequent select for the .sd-title rule as follows:

```
.single-post h3.sd-title 
{
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

In normal css, following the order of operations the last rule will be applied. So you in that case you can either move the .sd-title declaration after the .single-post h3 declaration or you can add !important to the end of the font-family rule in .sd-title to force it to override the .single-post h3 rule.

```
<style amp-custom>
     .sd-title {
        font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
        font-size: 12px;
     }
     .single-post h3 {
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
        line-height: 1.6;
     }
  </style>
```

Comment: I was already aware of those two solutions but I can't change the order since these rules are inserted inline in this order by wordpress plugins. I can't use !important because that isn't allowed on AMP pages. I was hoping for some way to increase the specificity so that it chooses the first rule but everything I tried failed.

Comment: Can you add additional rules?

Comment: Yes, I can add additional rules using the plugin that's adding the html but those rules appear above the conflicting rule. The "sd-title" rule was one that I added. If there's no way to fix the specificity of this rule, then I will need to figure out how to add the css rule after the conflicting rule.

Comment: Okay, then I updated my answer I wasn't aware you had that ability. .single-post h3.sd-title will override .single-post h3 regardless of order.

Comment: Changing the order didn't make any difference. But your new rule solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The trick was to put use ".single-post h3.sd-title" instead of ".single-post .sd-title h3"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `!important` rule to ensure the style is not overwritten. For example:

```
.sd-title {
     font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
     font-size: 12px !important;
}
```